# Integrate a Dirichlet Posterior over a finite interval

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

How do you integrate (analytically or numerically) a Dirichlet Posterior over a finite interval or union of finite intervals of events/rvs $x_i$

Comment: Posterior? I hope the good Professor Dirichlet smiles on us from above.

Comment: This one isn't an autocorrect error: "posterior probability" is a bona fide technical term.

Comment: Posterior which is a dirichlet distribution!

Comment: The domain of the Dirichlet distribution is a simplex, not an interval (except in the $1$-dimensional case).  Can you clarify what set you want to integrate over? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: To whom it may concern: "prior" and "posterior" are adjectives that are frequently used as nouns by abbreviating the phrases "prior probability distribution" and "posterior probability distribution". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Denote posterior P(a|D) where 'a' is the set of parameters and 'D' is data. I want to integrate P(a|D) over a feasible set 'A', a(\in)A

Comment: I am trying to compute a confidence for the feasible set.

Comment: Let us denote the feasible set as a hyper-rectangle, each dimension is a finite interval